# How to Display Text Over a Hero/Section Video

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I'm having a little trouble displaying my text over a full screen video I have on my site. I had it working before but can't remember how I achieved it and have tried z-index properties with no luck, the text just keeps displaying under my video element rather than on top.

I have made a few edits and not realised the panel messed up and don't have an old version to fall-back on.

Here is what I have so far, I'm probably just overlooking something but not sure why it isn't working for me.

```
 <section class="section-ux-design">

        <video id="video" autoplay loop muted>
            <source src="/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">

        </video>

        <div class="overlay-text">
            <h2>Text</h2>
            <p>Text</p>

        </div>

    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.section-ux-design {
    position: relative;
}

.overlay-text {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0% 15%;
    z-index: 0;
}

.overlay-text h2 {
    text-align: left;
}

#video {
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

I'm looking to achieve something like this: https://sparkengine.tv/, but just with text as this is not going to be my main hero/header video.

Answer (score 2):

```
.overlay-text {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0% 15%;
    z-index: 0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

That should put the text container over the video and you can position the text from there.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! I had a top and left property previously I think, thats what was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define *position* for your #video element as z-index only affects elements with position value other than static (which is the default).

You should also try specifying the actual absolute coordinates of the .overlay-text, as otherwise it will just get pushed below the video section. I amended with the following ant works fine for me:

```
.section-ux-design {
    position: relative;
}

.overlay-text {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0% 15%;
    z-index: 0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.overlay-text h2 {
    text-align: left;
}

#video {
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: -1;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Oh I haven't included that but I have tried positioning as relative which makes no difference.

Comment: @CaitlinMooney I thought that by under you meant under the video layer. Setting the coordinates for overlay-text will help then :)

Comment: Thanks! Yes I think I had top and left properties previously that I removed for some reason and forgot to put back, thats what was missing.